# mark if combine of multiple textbox value match in while loop table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need little help to solve my problem. i have a table with mysql/php while loop. and two textbox with query value like

```
<tbody>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
<tr>
<td><input name="telephone_number" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['telephone_number'];?>"/></td>
<td><input name="priority" type="text"  value="<?php echo $row['priority'];?>" /></td>
<td>.....</td>
<td>.....</td>
</tr>
<?php }  ?>
</tbody>
```

Now lets say if telephone number val- 888 and priority val- 0 both altogether  match with other row then all matched row(tr) colored with class say class_matched.

so far i can do with one textbox with textbox background color with the help of stackoverflow. but cant figure out for both textbox and add class inside tr.

```
$('#table1').find("input[name='telephone_number']").each(function() {
if ($this.val().length > 1) {   
$(this).addClass('class_matched');
}
});
```

Thanks in advance for help. sincerely apologize if duplicate.

Edited: and also i want to implement on change event for both textbox.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Comment: I would try to do this in PHP.  Sort your query by number, priority, keep track of the last row you added, if the next row has the same values add class_matched class to the tr.

Comment: Like i said if row1 telephone number value is - 888 and and priority value is 1. and row2 telephone number value is - 888 and and priority value is 1. then both are same, so row1 and row2 will be colored same class. else if row2 telephone number value is - 888 and and priority value is 2 then no class will assign.

Comment: @James thanks for look at. but i want if user change value of textbox then they can see if it match or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i have done at last. and its working for me what i wanted. still i will accept if someone make it better way. thanks to all stackoverflow.

[here is my JSfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/Rezbin/Lpb3ux3g/)

```js
function find_match() {
var allName = []; 

$('#table1 tbody tr').each(function(index1, value1) {
  var tele_loop1 = $(this).find("input[name='telephone_number']").val();
  var priority_loop1 = $(this).find("input[name='priority']").val();
  var tel_p_loop1 = tele_loop1 +'-'+ priority_loop1;
  allName.push(tel_p_loop1);
});



$('#table1 tbody tr').each(function(index1, value1) {
  var tele_loop2 = $(this).find("input[name='telephone_number']").val();
  var priority_loop2 = $(this).find("input[name='priority']").val();
  var tel_p_loop2 = tele_loop2 +'-'+ priority_loop2;

var itemsFound = $.grep(allName, function (elem) {
                              return elem == tel_p_loop2;
                           }).length;         
  if(itemsFound > 1){
 $(this).addClass('class_matched');
  }else{
  $(this).removeClass(); 
  }

});
};


$(document).ready(function () {
        find_match();
          $('#table1 tbody tr').on('input', '.num_p', function() {
            $(this).attr('value',this.value)
        });
  $('#table1 tbody tr').on('input', '.num_p',find_match);
    });
```

```css
.class_matched {
background: #99FF32;
}

.sortable {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #38678f;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: white;
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

.sortable th {
  background: steelblue;
  height: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #38678f;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #38678f;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #568ebd;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="sortable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="6%"> Number</th>
    <th width="4%">Priority</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="111" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="222" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="333" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="111" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="222" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="444" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="111" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="333" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="telephone_number" type="text" value="333" /></td>
      <td><input class="num_p" name="priority" type="text" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this code not working , see that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/c5fz6own/)

Comment: Its failed while 1. num = 222,Prio=0 and 2.  num = 22,Prio=20 its maching these too

Comment: @Govind you right. i have to evaluate separately as you did. thanks for showing the hole. ;-)

Comment: var tel_p_loop1 = tele_loop1 +'-'+ priority_loop1; and var tel_p_loop2 = tele_loop2 +'-'+ priority_loop2; this trick will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to two loops
2. Store outer loop val and then use second loop
3. Add class if matched with inner loop

```js
$('#table1 tr').each(function(i, e) {
  var ot = $(this).find("input[name='telephone_number']").val();
  var op = $(this).find("input[name='priority']").val();
  var isMatched = false;
  $('#table1 tr').each(function(j, k) {
    if (j > i) {
      var it = $(this).find("input[name='telephone_number']").val();
      var ip = $(this).find("input[name='priority']").val();
      if (it == ot && ip == op) {
        $(this).addClass('class_matched');
        isMatched = true;
      }
    }
  });
  if (isMatched) {
    $(this).addClass('class_matched');
  }
});
```

```css
.class_matched {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="telephone_number" type="text" value="888" /></td>
      <td><input name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="telephone_number" type="text" value="999" /></td>
      <td><input name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="telephone_number" type="text" value="888" /></td>
      <td><input name="priority" type="text" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. just tried from last 7days and it took 7sec for you.it sloved my problem. however with 50 row table it loop 50*50 = 2500 times. anyway to improve performance?

Comment: Can anybody please help me to solve this to add on change event? So far Dear Govind Samrow solved my problem but i tried to add on change event and it not working well.

Comment: I think its different ques and you need to ask new ques for this

Comment: Thanks again Govind. just afraid of duplicating question.